# Obtaining number of functional groups in a compound from SMILES, SDF or MOL2 format

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I'm looking for a tool that can give how many methyl groups, hydroxyl groups etc are in a compound's structure presented as SMILES, SDF or MOL2 format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/is-there-an-algorithm-that-counts-joback-groups-in-a-structure

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous programs, but it's pretty easy to use the [obgrep](https://openbabel.org/wiki/Obgrep) tool in Open Babel to do this using SMARTS for the various functional groups:

- `obgrep -c '[CX3]' file.sdf # count the number of methyl groups`
- `obgrep -c '[#6][OX2H]' file.sdf # count the number of hydroxyl groups`

etc. Examples of functional groups using SMARTS can be found on the Daylight [SMARTS examples](http://www.daylight.com/dayhtml_tutorials/languages/smarts/smarts_examples.html) page.

I've also written scripts in Python for these purposes - depends on how you want to run the SMARTS searches.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For testing I've used [this](http://www.hmdb.ca/structures/metabolites/HMDB37025.sdf) file, it contains two methyl groups but the command:
`obgrep -c '[CX3]' HMDB37025.sdf ` returning 0!